# Why are alpha hydroxy acids stable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

We were told by our teacher that 4 hydroxyl groups on same carbon atom results in formation of carbon dioxide by removal of 2 water molecules and he also told that 3 hydroxyl groups on the same Carbon results in formation of carboxylic acid.

So now the carbon with 4 hydroxyl groups can be thought of as a carbon with an acid group and a hydroxy group (which gives us carbon dioxide).

But today he told us that alpha hydroxy acids( comp. with a carbon atom with both acid group and hydroxy group) do not decompose into Carbon dioxide but gave no reason.

**Why is this true ?**

Comment: There's hardly any comparison between [ortho acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortho_acid) and alpha hydroxy acids

Comment: Still, if you need some logic, then carbocation formed as intermediate in elimination of water in ortho acids is way more stable.

Comment: The gist is that 'an acid group' (COOH) implicitly includes a carbon atom. So a different carbon connected to an acid group and a hydroxy group is actually $\ce{R-CHOH-COOH}$ and does not decompose to $\ce{CO2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, an α-hydroxy acid does *not* have multiple functional groups on the same carbon atom. It has a carboxyl group centered on one carbon and an hydroxyl group on an adjacent carbon; the latter is the α in "α-hydroxy acid". If the additional hydroxyl group were two carbon atoms away would be a β-hydroxy acid, three carbons away would be a γ-hydroxy acid, and so on. The term ω-hydroxy acid is sometimes used to describe a molecule with a chain of carbon atoms having carboxyl at one end and hydroxyl at the other.

Hydroxy acids are not completely inert. Having both a carboxyl function and an additional hydroxyl function means they can form esters with themselves, which may lead to ringed or polymeric structures. In the case of α-hydroxy acids the result is [polymers that may have generated templates for the creation of early organisms](https://www.eurekalert.org/news-releases/886115).